# Making absolute path from reltive url in crawl spider

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to make absolute urls out of these relative urls. Tried to use process_links but in vain. Any suggestions?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class FfySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'FFy'
    allowed_domains = ['cartoon3rbi.net']
    start_urls = ['https://www.cartoon3rbi.net/cats-pages-1.html/']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="cartoon_cat_name"]'), process_links='make_absolute_path',
             callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        yield {

            'name': response.xpath('//div[@class="cartoon_eps_name"]/a/text()[2]').extract(),
        }

    def make_absolute_path(self, links):
        for link in links:
            url = 'https://www.cartoon3rbi.net/' + link
            return url
```

Comment: the xpath in the rule gives no links, can you specify which links are you trying to follow?

Comment: the links to the episodes of the shows on first page

Answer (score 2):

From **scrapy** documentation:
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules

> process_links is a callable, or a string (in which case a method from the spider object with that name will be used) which will be called for each list of links extracted from each response using the specified link_extractor. This is mainly used for filtering purposes.

I think function specified by `process_links` is called with a list of links and should be returning a list of links (or a generator).

```py
    def make_absolute_path(self, links):
        for link in links:
            url = 'https://www.cartoon3rbi.net/' + link
            yield url
```